# Jquery Range Validation function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have two number text fields in my page, say field1 and field2. field1 range is between 1 and 12. When field1 value is 1, only then the user should be allowed to enter value in field2. Again field2 range is between 1 and 12.

I want to add the range validation for field2 based on the value of field1. Is there anyway I can add jQuery function like this.

```
field2: {
    range: function(){
        if($("#field1").val() == 1){
            return "[1,12]";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, how can I restrict the user from entering any value in field2, when field1 value is not 1.

Comment: can you provide the relevant HTML or add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Show the rest of the relevant code.  By leaving out the relevant markup, you're making more work for the people trying to help you.

Comment: Sorry Sparky, yes it was a typo. I updated my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be working if you fix three small errors...

1. Use `.val()`, not `.val`
2. Use `return [1, 12]`, not `"return [1, 12]"`
3. Use `$('[name="field1"]')`, rather than `$("#field2")`.  You can't compare the field's value to itself.  Perhaps just a typo.

**jQuery**:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            field1: {
                required: true
            },
            field2: {
                required: true,
                range: function () {
                    if ($('[name="field1"]').val() == 1) {
                        return [1, 12];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });

});
```

**HTML**:

```
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" name="field1" />
    <br/>
    <input type="text" name="field2" />
    <br />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/6000rp0b/**

Answer (score 0):

You might look at a two-way binding library like Knockout or Angular for this depending on how heavy your actual application is. To do it just with vanilla Javascript or jQuery you'll need to bind an event handler to your input elements and modify their properties as appropriate, something like:

```
$("#field1").on("input", function() {
  $("#field2").prop("disabled", this.value != 1); // or readonly
});
```

If you want to post your HTML and expand on what exactly you're wanting it to do I can fiddle this up.